# How can I force template parameter type to be signed?

Tags: c++, templates

I'll use the following example to illustrate my question:

```
template<typename T>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a-b;
}
```

I expect this template function works only when the type T is signed. The only solution I can figure out is to use delete keyword for all the unsigned types:

```
template<>
unsigned char diff(unsigned char,unsigned char) == delete;
template<>
unsigned char diff(unsigned char,unsigned char) == delete;
```

Are there other solutions?

Comment: [`std::is_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned) may help you (or `is_signed`). Haven't thought exactly how to write it yet, but some sort of SFINAE.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `std::is_signed` together with `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T>
T diff(T a, T b);

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value, T> diff(T a, T b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

Here `std::is_signed<T>::value` is `true` if and only if `T` is signed (BTW, it is also `true` for floating-point types, if you don't need it, consider combining with `std::is_integral`).

`std::enable_if_t<Test, Type>` is the same as `std::enable_if<Test, Type>::type`. `std::enable_if<Test, Type>` is defined as an empty struct in case `Test` is false and as a struct with an only typedef `type` equal to template parameter `Type` otherwise.

So, for signed types, `std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value, T>` is equal to `T`, while for unsigned it's not defined and compiler uses SFINAE rule, so, if you need to specify an implementation for a particular non-signed type, you can easily do that:

```
template<>
unsigned diff(unsigned, unsigned)
{
    return 0u;
}
```

Some relevant links: [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), [is_signed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed).

Comment: I would not use `enable_if` in this case since it doesn't provide useful information at compile time. Only tells you that the symbol is not found... not cool in this peculiar context.

Comment: I think the code would be cleaner if instead of specialising a `template` you merely overload a function. That is, you don't need the initial `template` declaration and the specialisation for `unsigned` just becomes an overload (no need for "`template<>`").

Comment: @misterwhy, Agree that `static_assert` is preferrable here

Answer (score 36):

How about [`static assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) with [`std::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) ?

```
template<typename T>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
    static_assert(std::is_signed<T>::value, "signed values only");
    return a-b;
}
```

See it live there : 
http://ideone.com/l8nWYQ

Comment: Good answer, but note that `static_assert` without a message is going to be added in C++17 and this question is tagged with C++11 and C++14.

Comment: @December so what would be wrong with just adding a message?

Comment: @Spencer Not much, and in my opinion it doesn't interfere with Louen's intent.

Comment: I almost always prefer `static_assert` to SFINAE, as it produces nicer error messages. OTOH, a `static_assert` means you can't SFINAE off the function in the future. At the very least, I think that most public API functions should be `static_assert`s

Comment: Yes sorry about  the non-messaging `static_assert`. Thanks for editing !

Answer (score 11):

I would use `static_assert` with a nice error message. `enable_if` will only get your IDE in trouble and fail to compile with a message like

> identifier `diff` not found

which doesn't help much.

So why not like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
    static_assert(std::is_signed< T >::value, "T should be signed");
    return a - b;
}
```

that way, when you invoke `diff` with something else than a signed type, you will get the compiler to write this kind of message:

> error: T should be signed

with the location and the values to the call to `diff` and that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Why would `enable_if` *get the IDE in trouble*?

Comment: Trouble is a strong word; what I actually meant is that your IDE cannot prevent you from typing `diff(1, 2u)` but then, because of `enable_if`, it would kind of make the function disappear thus highlighting a mistake without telling you where you are wrong.

Answer (score 7):

As another option, you might probably add *static_assert* with *std::is_signed* type trait:

```
template<typename T>
auto diff(T x, T y)
{
    static_assert(std::is_signed<T>::value, "Does not work for unsigned");
    return x - y;
}
```

So that:

```
auto x = diff(4, 2); // works
auto x = diff(4U, 2U); // does not work
```

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few issues I have with your function.

First, your function requires all 3 types to match -- the left, right and result types.  So `signed char a; int b; diff(a-b);` won't work for no good reason.

```
template<class L, class R>
auto diff( L l, R r )
-> typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_signed<L>::value && std::is_signed<R>::value,
  typename std::decay<decltype( l-r )>::type
>::type
{
  return l-r;
}
```

the second thing I'd want to do is make a diff object; you cannot easily pass your `diff` function around, and higher order functions are awesome.

```
struct diff_t {
  template<class L, class R>
  auto operator()(L l, R r)const
  -> decltype( diff(l,r) )
  { return diff(l,r); }
};
```

Now we can pass `diff_t{}` to an algorithm, as it holds the "overload set" of `diff` in one (trivial) C++ object.

Now this is serious overkill.  A simple `static_assert` can also work.

The `static_assert` will generate better error messages, but won't support other code using SFINAE to see if `diff` can be called.  It will simply generate a hard error.

Answer (score 2):

What does your program expect as a result?  As it stands, you return an unsigned as a result of a difference.  IMHO, this is a bug waiting to happen.

```
#include <type_trait>

template<typename T>
auto diff(T&& a, T&& b)
{
    static_assert (std::is_unsigned<T>::value);
    return typename std::make_signed<T>::type(a - b);
}
```

A more modern wait to write this:

```
inline auto diff(const auto a, const auto b)
{
    static_assert (   std::is_unsigned<decltype(a)>::value 
                   && std::is_unsigned<decltype(b)>::value );
    return typename std::make_signed<decltype(a -b)>::type(a - b);
}
```

[edit] I feel the need to add this comment: using unsigned integral types in math equations is always tricky.  The example above would be a very useful add-on to any math package, if real-life situations, you often have to resort to casting to make the result of differences `signed`, or the math doesn't work.

Comment: What proprietary compiler extension does your "more modern wait" use? That's not Standard C++. Functions (not including lambdas) cannot have `auto`-typed arguments. Therefore, it's not a good recommendation IMO.

Comment: Standard ISO c++17.

Comment: Then you'll have no problem showing me a trip report or etc where that paper was accepted. I can find no evidence that it was: only notes that it's part of one or more Concepts proposals. In which case, no, it's not C++17.

Comment: Use any modern compiler and check it out for youirself `int main() {  return diff(5u, 8u); }` copmpiles to `mov     eax, -3'` `ret` on gcc 7.1  optiions: -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall.  on compiler explorer today.

Comment: What compilers allow isn't proof. (And the generated assembly is even more irrelevant.) So I'll ask again: Do you have a link about what the Standard says? That's all that matters. What compilers allow says very little about what the Standard allows (ultimate case in point: UB). IIRC, some of them enable some non-standard extensions even in 'standard' modes, unless given `-Wpedantic` or equivalent. And again, I don't recall seeing any indication that `auto` for function arguments had made it into C++17, or even a non-draft TS.

Comment: ...and oh, look at that: `warning: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]`

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody answered this, which is pretty robust and reliable and IMO canonical since and after C++11.

```
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value>::type>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a-b;
}
```

in C++14 you can use:

```
template<typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value>>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a-b;
}
```

in C++17 you can use:

```
template<typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>>>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a-b;
}
```

This alternative could help with multiple "overloads" if necessary (I will leave it at there)

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>,int> =0>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a-b;
}
```

...and in C++20 you can use Concepts (not shown).

Comment: Inexhaustible C++ syntax... +1 to move it up

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers here, however this question comes up as a result of the search *"c++ template argument signed"*. We are in 2022 now, so I think it makes sense to add an answer, using **concepts** in C++20:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <std::signed_integral T>
T diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a - b;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << diff(1U, 2U) << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler fails to compile the program above with the message (among others):

```
error: use of function ‘T diff(T, T) [with T = unsigned int]’ with unsatisfied constraints
```

The **core language concept** `std::signed_integral`, used here, is described on this [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<(0>-T(1)),T> diff(T a, T b)
{
  return a-b;
}
```

use (0>-T(1)) ,I assume init T for -1 will less than 0.  and unsigned value not possible less than 0

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Especially when the code is written with such dense, unreadable formatting.

Comment: This answer is very anachronistic, it uses C++14 features without fully exploiting other C++14 features. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71670164/225186